# Show $F(z)=\int_{0}^{1}{g(t)\over t-z}dt$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$. Limit problem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Show $\int_{0}^{1}{g(t)\over t-z}dt$, $g(t):[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ a continuous function, is holomorphic in $\Bbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$. Trying to simplify ${F(z+h)-F(z)\over h}$ I arrived at $\int_{0}^{1}{g(t)\over (t-z)(t-(z+h))}dt$, and I don't know how I better compute its limit as $h\to 0$. Can I put the limit inside? How? Following Calculus, I only know I can do this for $n$ functions (countable ones) uniformly converging to $F$ but this is not the case. In addition, I don't know how to relate to $[0,1]$ points in this process so at to truly be sure how they can or can't impact the convergence of the limit above. I would appreciate your help.

Edit: I added more tags mentioning Real Analysis because I don't want to ignore the probability that one whose expertise is Real Analysis and not Complex Analysis will be able to give a Real-Analysis-based explanation

Comment: What is $g$ ..........?

Comment: You have miscopied or miscalculated. $$\frac{1}{t - (z+h)} - \frac{1}{t-z} = \frac{h}{(t - (z+h))(t-z)},$$ so your denominator ought to be $(t-z)(t-(z+h))$, not $z(z+h)$.

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to mention it. I edited my question.

Comment: Daniel, I think you are correct. Let me check it again. If what I wrote really were the case, I wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: That doesn't affect the argument, however. In any case, we have uniform convergence of the integrand as $h \to 0$, so you can bring the limit inside the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}
\left|\dfrac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}-\int_0^1 \frac{g(t)}{(t-z)^2}\,dt\right|&=\left|\frac1h\int_0^1 g(t)\left(\dfrac{1}{t-(z+h)}-\dfrac{1}{t-z}-\frac{h}{(t-z)^2}\right)\,dt\right|\\\\
&=\left|\int_0^1 g(t)\left(\dfrac{1}{(t-z)(t-z-h)}-\frac{1}{(t-z)^2}\right)\,dt\right|\\\\
&=\left|\int_0^1 \dfrac{hg(t)}{(t-z)^2(t-z-h)}\,dt\right|\\\\
&\le\int_0^1 \dfrac{|h|\,|g(t)|}{(t-z)^2|t-z-h|}\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> We note that $|t-z-h|=\sqrt{(t-h)^2-2\text{Re}(z)(t-h)+|z|^2}\ge \left|\text{Im}(z)\right|$.  Therefore, we have $$\int_0^1\left|\dfrac{hg(t)}{(t-z)^2(t-z-h)}\right|\,dt\le \dfrac{h}{\left|\text{Im}(z)\right|}\int_0^1\dfrac{|g(t)|}{(t-z)^2}\,dt \tag 1$$Since the integrand in $(1)$ is bounded and independent of $h$, then it is easy to see that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1\left|\dfrac{hg(t)}{(t-z)^2(t-z-h)}\right|\,dt=0$$And this completes the proof that $F(z)$ is differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying. What I find harder is the actual computing of the limit.

Comment: I added the solution in a "Spoiler Alert" section.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. Can I ask why absolute value is needed?
Does it prove differentiability without the absolute value?

Comment: You're welcome.  Here, the "absolute value" is the complex magnitude.  The development establishes that the upper bound for the magnitude (which is non-negative) can be made arbitrarily small (i.e., less than any pre-assigned $\epsilon>0$) by choosing $h$ sufficiently small.  That means that the limit of the difference quotient approaches the integral of $\int_0^1 g(t)\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(\dfrac{1}{t-z}\right)\,dt$. So, yes. This proves that $F$ is differentiable for all $z$ in the stated domain.

Comment: I could really use elaboration on the note hidden above.

Comment: I'm happy to help.  So, please help me understand where you would like clarification/elucidation.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
Please double check your result of ${F(z+h)-F(z)\over h}$
$${F(z+h)-F(z)\over h}=\frac{1}{h}(\int_{0}^{1}{g(t)\over t-(z+h)}dt-\int_{0}^{1}{g(t)\over t-z}dt)$$

$${F(z+h)-F(z)\over h}=\frac{1}{h}(\int_{0}^{1}{[(t-z)-(t-z-h)] g(t)\over (t-(z+h))(t-z)}dt)$$
$${F(z+h)-F(z)\over h}=\frac{1}{h}(\int_{0}^{1}{h g(t)\over (t-(z+h))(t-z)}dt)$$

$$\lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{ {F(z+h)-F(z)\over h} }= \lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{  \frac{1}{h}(\int_{0}^{1}{h g(t)\over (t-(z+h))(t-z)}dt)}$$

$$\lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{ {F(z+h)-F(z)\over h} }= \lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{  \frac{h}{h}(\int_{0}^{1}{ g(t)\over (t-(z+h))(t-z)}dt)}$$

$$\lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{ {F(z+h)-F(z)\over h} }= \lim\limits_{ h\to 0  }{  (\int_{0}^{1}{ g(t)\over (t-(z+h))(t-z)}dt)}=\int_{0}^{1}{ g(t)\over (t-z)^2}dt$$

Comment: Yes I just arrived at it. My main problem is the handling of this limit.

Comment: What justifies moving the limit inside the integral? This is what I couldn't explain.

Comment: The integral depends on $t$ but we take limit on $h$.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but still, there's got to be a formal way to justify it. Regardless of this specific case, because after all, it's not the same function as $h$ changes, so what keeps it legitimate? Continuity? I have been looking for formal theorem and restrictions and haven't come by something to unequivocally support this procedure.

Comment: Please check Leibniz integral rule. The proof has similiar idea. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proofs  Then have a look the title 'General form with variable limits' in the page